# Pandas, set value based on sequence of index+column pairs

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I would like to fill an empty dataframe using sequence of specific index/column label pairs.

```
In [3]: test = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([6,6]), index=list('ABCDEF'), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
```

In numpy you can fill an array pointwise when providing two disjoint lists of numerical indices for two axis.

```
In [4]: test.values[((0,1,2,3,4),(0,0,2,3,3))]=88
In [5]: test
Out[5]: 
      A    B     C     D    E    F
A  88.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0
B  88.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0
C   0.0  0.0  88.0   0.0  0.0  0.0
D   0.0  0.0   0.0  88.0  0.0  0.0
E   0.0  0.0   0.0  88.0  0.0  0.0
F   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0
```

However, same notation in pandas returns a subset of the dataframe and fills whole quadrant.

```
In [7]: test.loc[('A','B','C','D','E'), ('A','A','B','C','C')]=88
In [8]: test # df.loc, df.iloc and df.at all return same result
Out[8]: 
      A     B     C    D    E    F
A  88.0  88.0  88.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
B  88.0  88.0  88.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
C  88.0  88.0  88.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
D  88.0  88.0  88.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
E  88.0  88.0  88.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
F   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Currently I'm switching from alphabetic to numerical indices and use numpy elements access, but I wonder, is there a more clear and consise solution?

```
test.values[ [list(test.index).index(x) for x in ('A','B','C','D','E')],
         [list(test.columns).index(x) for x in ('A','A','B','C','C')]]=88
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of for loop here

```
for x , y in zip(('A','B','C','D','E'), ('A','A','B','C','C')):
    test.at[x, y] = 88 

test
Out[294]: 
      A     B     C    D    E    F
A  88.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
B  88.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
C   0.0  88.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
D   0.0   0.0  88.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
E   0.0   0.0  88.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
F   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Congratulations on 100k :)

Comment: Thx for your answer and congrats! 
Seems like for loop is actually the fastest solution (~26.8 µs ± 271ns vs ~71µs for mine and ~1.51ms for Scott's.)

Comment: Yep, this is much caster.  Just giving you an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use dataframe reshaping:

```
t1 = test.stack()

t1.loc[zip(('A','B','C','D','E'), ('A','A','B','C','C'))] = 88

t1.unstack()
```

Output:

```
      A     B     C    D    E    F
A  88.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
B  88.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
C   0.0  88.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
D   0.0   0.0  88.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
E   0.0   0.0  88.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
F   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```